# npm: Tried to reinstall admob-free plugin but it throws an error about not containing a package.json file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I'm using Ionic to make an app and for some reason the AdMob plugin was not installed correctly, so I tried to reinstall it. However, I kept on getting an error. I checked a couple of threads for some help and ended up following one these thread's advice. I deleted my `package-locked.json` file and my `node_modules` folder then I tried to run npm i and got the error below. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Failed to fetch plugin file:node_modules/cordova-plugin-admob-free via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules/cordova-plugin-admob-free" as it does not contain a package.json file.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tatsuo/.npm/_logs/2019-06-13T05_12_13_705Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You need a pacakage.json file is missing ..Check your project file is available or not

Comment: If you run npm update package-lock.json gets updated and the new dependency is installed.

Comment: I have a package.json file in my project directory. I tried running npm update package-lock.json and then tried npm install, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm init
```

Original Outdated Answer

I think you forgot to setup the directory for express:

```
express <yourdirectory>
```

Once you do that you should be able to see a bunch of files, you should then run the command:

```
npm install -d
```

Comment: What is the express command? I don't have that command on my system.